# Display all SQL queries within a single PHP script execution

Tags: php, mysql

There is a long living large project in PHP, in the development of which at different times were involved a number of different developers. Potentially, there may have been places where duplicate database queries were made during bug fixing. Some developer to solve a local problem could write and execute a query returning data that were previously obtained. Now on the project there is a problem of DB performance and in light of it a have a question:

**Are there any tools (besides General Log) that allow you to see what database queries were made as part of a single PHP script execution?**

The question is related to the fact that there are a lot of API endpoints in the project and it will take a long time to check them all just by reading the code (which is sometimes very ornate).

Comment: MySQL organizes queries in processes. You also could activate a binlog.

Comment: Does the project use a database wrapper of some kind?

Comment: @thephper Unfortunately no db wrapper involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most PHP frameworks use a single connection interface - some kind of wrapper - that makes it possible to log all queries through that interface.

If that does not exist another approach would be to enable logging at the MySQL-level. But for some, probably legit, reason you don't want to do that either. If you want to prevent downtime you can actually [enable query logging without restarting the MySQL server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098836/how-to-enable-general-log-without-restarting-the-mysql-server)

If none of the above solutions is possible you have to get your hands dirty :-)

One way could be to add your own logging in the PHP code.
Writing new lines to a file is not a performance issue if you *write to the end of the file*.

I'm not sure how you query the database, but if you..

**A) ..use the procedural mysqli functions**

If you use the procedural mysqli functions like mysqli_query() to call the database you could create your own global custom function which writes to the log file and then call the real function.

An example:

Add the new global function:

```
function _mysqli_query($link, $query, $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT )
{
    // write new line to end of log-file
    file_put_contents('queries.log', $query . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

    // call real mysqli_query
    return mysqli_query($link, $query, $resultmode);
}
```

The do a project-wide search and replace for *mysqli_query(* with *_mysqli_query(*.

Then a line like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'select * from users');
```

Would look like this after the search and replace:

```
$result = _mysqli_query($conn, 'select * from users');
```

**B) ..use the mysqli class (object oriented style)**

If you use the object oriented style by instantiation the mysqli class and then calling the query methods e.g. $mysqli->query("select * from users") an approach could be to create your own database class which extends the mysqli class, and inside the specific methods (e.g. the query function) you add the logging like in the above example.

In the highly recommendable book "High Performance MySQL" from O'Reilly they go through code examples how to do this and add extra debug information (timing etc.). Some of the pages are [accessible at google books](https://books.google.dk/books?id=BL0NNoFPuAQC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22class%20mysqlx%20extends%20mysqli%22&source=bl&ots=CQXNzuqI5T&sig=ACfU3U2nupIoHB0ofXan5WMGdo1SwB0Lwg&hl=da&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEiOnltKfoAhVQLewKHbh1APYQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22class%20mysqlx%20extends%20mysqli%22&f=false).

**In general**

I would consider using this as an opportunity to refactor some of the codebase to the better.

If you have written automated tests that is a good way to ensure that the refactoring did not break anything.

If you do not practice automated testing you have to test the whole application manually.

You said that you are afraid that your performance issues comes from duplicate database queries, which might very well be the case.
In most cases I find it to be missing indexes though or a need to rewrite single queries.

The performance schema in MySQL can help you debug these things if you find it realistic that it could be other causes to the performance issues.

Comment: Did my answer help you @DieHardHen ?